# how to assign PHP variable in a button ID

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my PHP variable and a button which is generated using 'echo'. Now I want to insert the id of the button. How I will do that.
Please help me. Code is given below.

```
if ($unconfirmed_cities) {
    foreach ($unconfirmed_cities as $unconfirmed_city) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo "$unconfirmed_city[name]";
        echo '<input type="button" id= "$unconfirm_city[name]" value="Accept" class="mybut btn btn-info btn-mini" style="">';
        echo '</div>';  
    }
}
```

Now as given the input `type = "button"`in the echo tag and I have inserted the id but it is not working.How to do this.

Comment: I think that is something wrong with [name] - shouldn't it be ["name"] ?

Comment: @radeczek No, without any quotes it's correct too.

Comment: But it was not working in my code that's why I told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
 echo '<input type="button" id= "'.$unconfirm_city['name'].'" value="Accept" class="mybut btn btn-info btn-mini" style="">';
```

Comment: You missed the closing single quote.By the way thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of typo on your code. Try this way

```
<?php
if ($unconfirmed_cities) {
foreach ($unconfirmed_cities as $unconfirmed_city) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo $unconfirmed_city[name];
    echo '<input type="button" id= '.$unconfirmed_city[name].'" value="Accept" class="mybut btn btn-info btn-mini" style="">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   echo '<input type="button" id= "'.$unconfirm_city[name].'" value="Accept" class="mybut btn btn-info btn-mini" style="">'
```

Check this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php  
 if ($unconfirmed_cities) {  
        foreach ($unconfirmed_cities as $unconfirmed_city) {  
         echo '<div>';  
 echo "$unconfirmed_city[name]";  
 echo '<input type=\'button\' id= \''.$unconfirm_city[name].'\' value=\'Accept\' class=\'mybut btn btn-info btn-mini\' style=\'\'>';  
echo '</div>';  
} 

?>
```

Note: In \', (slash) is used as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the quotes, so $unconfirm_city is considered as string rather than variable by PHP.

Replace following line in your code,

```
echo '<input type="button" id= "$unconfirm_city[name]" value="Accept" class="mybut btn btn-info btn-mini" style="">';
```

by,

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"".$unconfirm_city['name']."\" value=\"Accept\" class=\"mybut btn btn-info btn-mini\" style=\"\">";
```